# c# - maintaining state of a variable everytime an object is created

Tags: c#

```
  static int next;
    partial void OnCreated()
    {
        next = next + 1;
        PurchaseOrderLineNo = next;
        this.RequestDueDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

> Issue here is static variable shares its value among all the instances of class.

now if i have added 12 values then thought of deleting them all, now what happens is the next time i add value it should be 1 instead it starts with 13. so i m confused how to achieve this scenario.

basically i am trying to show sequence number in my gridcontrol. i m using partial class of L2S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to maintain the value of a variable *across* multiple instances of a class, you need to make that variable *static*:

```
private static int PurchaseOrderLineNo { get; set; }
```

Then you use it without the `this` keyword, since that is used to reference *instance* variables:

```
NextState = PurchaseOrderLineNo + CurrentState;
```

Comment: I cannot do anything to PurchaseOrderLineNo as it is a part of auto generated Dbml class. i just have to assign incremented value to it.

Comment: Well then you haven't given us enough information for us to provide a useful answer. You need to give us more context in your question. I would guess then that you are dealing with multiple instances of your class when you should actually be dealing with just one.

Comment: i have rephrased the question. @rory.ap